# Reg Spring Batch Transaction

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

My Requirement is I need to have two datasource connected to Spring Batch Application.
1) One for Spring Batch Jobs and Executions storing 
2) One for Business Data Stroing, Processing and Retreiving.
I know that there are lot of solutions for achieving this. But I have achieved by setting the second datasource as primary. The problem is the second datasource is not coming under transaction scope instead it is committing for each sql statement executing expecially through jdbctemplate.

Comment: Can you explain..more about your problem by sharing some code

Comment: Hi Yogi I am not able to edit the question which i asked so am posting my question in detail as a answer to the same question. So please have a look and guide me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I can't able to edit my question. I am writing another Post in detail 
My Requirement is I need to have two datasource connected to Spring Batch Application. 
1) One for Spring Batch Jobs and Executions storing 
2) One for Business Data Stroing, Processing and Retreiving.

In **env-context.xml** I have following configuration

```
<!-- Enable annotations-->
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean primary="true" id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/DB2XADS"/>
</bean>

<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
    DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" primary="true"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- jdbcTemplate uses dataSource -->
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="batchTransactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

In **override-context.xml** I have the following code

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- jdbcTemplate uses dataSource -->
<bean id="batchDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/MySqlDS"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.honda.pddabulk.utility.MyBatchConfigurer">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="batchDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Use this to set additional properties on beans at run time -->
<bean id="placeholderProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/bootstrap/batch.properties
            </value>
           <value>classpath:/batch/batch-mysql.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>

<!-- Overrider job repository -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="databaseType" value="mysql"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="batchDataSource"/>
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="${batch.table.prefix}"/>
    <property name="maxVarCharLength" value="2000"/>
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="batchTransactionManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- Override job service -->
<bean id="jobService" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.service.SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="${batch.table.prefix}"/>
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
    <property name="jobLocator" ref="jobRegistry"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="batchDataSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- Override job launcher -->
<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="jobLauncherTaskExecutor" />
</bean>

<task:executor id="jobLauncherTaskExecutor" pool-size="21" rejection-policy="ABORT" />

<!-- Override job explorer -->
<bean id="jobExplorer"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="${batch.table.prefix}"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="batchDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

In **job-config.xml** I have the following code

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.honda.*">
     <context:exclude-filter type="regex" 
               expression="com.honda.pddabulk.utility.MyBatch*" /> 
</context:component-scan>
```

I have the custom Batch configurer set. Now the problem is when I try to execute queries with jdbctemplate for update and insert it is not under transaction which means @Transactional is not working.

Rather commit is happening for each method call. The example is

```
@Transactional
public void checkInsertion() throws Exception{
    try{
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES( 'A','AF' );
        throw new PddaException("custom error");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        int count=jdbcTemplate.update("ROLLBACK");
        log.info("DATA HAS BEEN ROLLBACKED SUCCESSFULLY... "+count);        
        throw ex; 
    }

}
```

In the above code I am trying to insert data and immediately I am also throwing a exception which means the insert should happen but commit will not. So we will not be able to see any data but unfortunately the commit is happening. Please some one help